# Redis , configure redis.conf from command line

Tags: redis, configuration, automation

[image]I try to create a automated process to install redis on multiple windows machines.

I saw .msi files that installs correctly. The way i install is from command line like this:

```
Redis-x64-3.2.100.msi /qb port=6379 maxmemory=750M
```

My goal is to automate the process of configuring the redis.conf file (Edit the Bind section)

I want to edit the **'Bind 127.0.0.1'** to **'Bind 0.0.0.0'**

I've looked for a lot of blogs and redis documentations but it seems like those are the arguments that the msi file works with.

Is there anyway that i can automatically configure the redis.conf file without editing manually the file itself after each installation?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you share your conf file ??

Comment: I did share now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this command with git-bash after Redis installation:

```
sed -i 's/bind 127.0.0.1/bind 0.0.0.0/g' redis.windows.conf
```